# Forfeiting a privilege: e.g. see deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, privileges

I recently was given a privilege to see deleted answers, after reaching 10K rep. I personally find that privilege rather noisy - maybe because of the way it is implemented, where deleted answers can appear mixed up with non-deleted ones.

I would like to know if there is a way (I haven't been able to find it) to filter out deleted answers - either as a global setting, as an option on the question page, or by allowing me to temporarily forfeit some of my privileges (e.g. by seeing in my profile a list of privileges with checkboxes so that I can opt-out from them - I would definitely opt-out from this one and possibly others).

Some of the privileges TBH feel to me like chores Stack Overflow is trying to assign to me :) - I don't necessarily feel them as privileges.

Comment: "Deleted ansers can apear mixed up with non-deleted ones" All of the deleted answers always show up at the bottom for me. Does a different sort show them between other non-deleted answers?

Comment: I want to post a good answer giving psycological support to people having to endure seeing dead answer. Then delete it, Change my profile picture to Bruce Willis in _The Sixth Sense_.

Comment: I guess I was trying to ask a more generic question to that. As in, I don't really see a benefit for me at the moment in me being a moderator to the site, if that makes my experience of the site noisier - doing community work makes sense to me in a non-profit environment, and I've often done volunteer work. When there is a company profiting from users' work, and users are not directly rewarded for that, then I tend to become more skeptical.

Comment: Interestingly, there is one privilege I can explicitly forfait in my settings page, and that is the privilege of not seeing ads ;)

Comment: My userscript [Sticky Post Headers & Question Table of Contents](https://stackapps.com/questions/7994/sticky-post-headers-question-table-of-contents) has an option to hide all deleted answers (preference is saved locally).

Answer (score 10):

There's no "setting" to hide deleted answers once you can see them.

You can, however, add some custom styling using a browser plugin like stylus ([chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en) / [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/)):

```
.deleted-answer {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This doesn't update the "answers" count just below the question, but I rarely look at that any way:

> [image]

Comment: You can write a userscript if updating the answer count is desirable.

Comment: True, but that's slightly too much effort for me :P

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest *you* specifically did it. Sorry, I meant a "you" as a general.

Comment: Pronouns are a mess xD

Comment: That's very much true...

Comment: This is useful. Although with this I won't know that there are deleted answers and won't become even curious to occasionally peek at them.

Comment: @CarlesBarrobés: So, exactly like before you got the privilege :D